# Is the End Endless?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As written in the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_End#Outer_islands), the outer islands of The End generate infinitely as far as you go.

But, as in the Overworld, there might be a border far away. I have reached 70000 negative X, and still everything was generating identically to the not so outer islands. It would be pretty strange if the End actually had no end.

So, my question is:  **is there any border or maximum generated block limit in the End?**

Comment: "As in the Overworld, there might be a border far away" - I thought one of the main features of Minecraft was that there was no border? It does go on indefinitely. So does the End.

Comment: As written on the [Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/World_border), _"The world border is essentially a giant bounding box; by default, its center lies at coordinates x:0, z:0, with a width and length of almost 30 million (29,999,984) blocks from both ends"_ that's it for the overworld. not sure if it is so in the End. I also have actually teleported  until the border in a "cheat" world. I didn't fin a border in the End so far, though.

Comment: Huh. Guess it's been a while since I last played.

Comment: Yes, there is a world border. See also this picture from the Minecraft Wiki: https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft-de.gamepedia.com/1/1c/Weltbarriere_Ende.png

Comment: For all *practical* purposes, the world *is* infinite. Reaching it without cheats is a huge challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the end is not endless.

As stated in the [Official Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/World_border):

> Its default size and location remain the same across all three dimensions.

Meaning that the world border in the end will also be the same as in the overworld, so around 30 million blocks away (from 0,0).

Comment: But on a server I play, the border in The Overworld is much more close than the border in The End. Yes, the Overworld border is changed, but still... You mentioned that it's the same as in the Overworld.

Comment: It's **default** size and location. As you said yourself, the overworld's world border has been changed, but that doesn't mean the ends has too.

Comment: The world border's position can be changed via commands. And maybe due to a plugin or due to some special commands, it can be made dimension-specific. @Quijibo

Answer (score 3):

The end is not endless.  It looks like the overworld border.

[image: End End]